# Are people taller now than they were in the 1200's? If so, by how much?

Tags: science-based

I've heard from several sources that people used to be a fair amount shorter than they are today because they didn't have a very well-rounded diet but I can't find a credible source that might help me determine just how much shorter people were...if, in fact, they were.

I'm thinking about a time travel story, if you didn't pick up on that, but I'm still trying to decide if I want to commit to writing such a thing.  I find myself thinking about it a lot...like how messed up would it be to find yourself 800 years in the past and realize that knowledge of basic first aid, CPR, and microorganisms make you the most qualified medical doctor?  How hard would it be to convince the medical establishment that bleeding isn't actually a treatment for anything and that the four humours are nonsense?

Comment: This might be better for the biology stack exchange, but yes most humans are now taller, partly due to better conditions.

Comment: How credible a source do you want?(1) If you want reliable answers from history your best bet is to ask tl in History SE, after doing some research. (2) There is plenty questions here in WB speculating on applicability of in medical knowledge to time travel, make a search here. (3) Also you have wrapped a lot of questions into one, this is not how this is supposed to work here.

Comment: @Trioxidane: Specifically than in the 1200s, yes. Compared to the 600s, not so much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you are asking about an historical fact that is easily researched on the interweb or more properly asked on history.stackexchange.com

Comment: Human body height is a function of nutrition and general health. As such, a general answer can not be given for all of humanity. One would have to choose a population from back then (native Americans are unsuitable because there are too few complete skeletons for robust statictics), and from today for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Europeans today are about [6 or 7 cm taller than in the 1200s](https://ourworldindata.org/human-height), on the average. But this is highly specific to the 1200s: for some reason, the 1200s and the 1700s were low points in the average hight of Europeans. For example, Europeans today are just about as tall as their ancestors in the early Middle Ages (the age of king Arthur or emperor Charlemagne), maybe about 2 cm taller.

Of course, as anything in anthropology, the average tells very little about any particular population. European subpopulation do not and never did have the same average height; and which populations are taller than others also changed during historical times.

Comment: Very true, even today the Dutch are the tallest population in Europe.

Comment: [Please try not to answer "bad" questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/please-dont-answer-and-or-upvote-bad-questions-yet) --- those that are fairly obviously off topic!